# AmCharts Legend

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am trying to replicate the following chart

[image]

The problem I have is how to make the legend in the left and in the middle of every box that stacks (Series word in each box). I have searched amCharts but no luck. Is there a way to do it or how to override or extend amCharts in order to achieve this behavior?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For displaying value labels, use [`labelText`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#labelText) proeprty.

Just set it to "[[value]]" in your graphs. I.e.:

```
"graphs": [{
  ...
  "labelText": "[[value]]"
}]
```

For the "legend" on the left, you will need to use [guides](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/Guide). It allows placing lines (optional) and labels at some preset values. You will need to pre-calculate the values at which to place them, though.

Here's a complete working example:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "dataProvider": [{
    "year": 2011,
    "value1": 13,
    "value2": 5,
    "value3": 4
  }, {
    "year": 2012,
    "value1": 22,
    "value2": 4,
    "value3": 5
  }, {
    "year": 2013,
    "value1": 35,
    "value2": 7,
    "value3": 4
  }],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "stackType": "regular",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "labelsEnabled": false,
    "tickLength": 0,
    "totalText": "[[total]]",
    "guides": [{
      "value": 6.5,
      "label": "Series #1",
      "fontSize": 15
    }, {
      "value": 15.5,
      "label": "Series #2",
      "fontSize": 15
    }, {
      "value": 20,
      "label": "Series #3",
      "fontSize": 15
    }]
  }],
  "graphs": [{
    "fillAlphas": 1,
    "fillColors": "#a0b1cf",
    "labelText": "[[value]]",
    "lineAlpha": 1,
    "lineColor": "#000",
    "title": "value1",
    "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
    "valueField": "value1"
  }, {
    "fillAlphas": 1,
    "fillColors": "#c5cde0",
    "labelText": "[[value]]",
    "lineAlpha": 1,
    "lineColor": "#000",
    "title": "value1",
    "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
    "valueField": "value2"
  }, {
    "fillAlphas": 1,
    "fillColors": "#dde6eb",
    "labelText": "[[value]]",
    "lineAlpha": 1,
    "lineColor": "#000",
    "title": "value1",
    "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
    "valueField": "value3"
  }],
  "categoryField": "year",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left"
  }

});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: its working fine! what about if i need to move guides to the right side (so be next to 2013 bar) ?

Comment: It works! thanks a lot! well if you have time and maybe know, I have added trend-lines to replicate the dashed line (the one which points the arrow). My problem is that a trend line starts in the middle of the category (2012) and ends in the middle of the target category (2013). Is there an easy work around how to make it start in the end of 2012 category and end in the start of the 2013 one?